# How to replace internet explorer error pages

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to replace the internet explorer error pages - mainly those with links to various repair and troubleshooting actions (such as res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm: "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage")

I saw there's a way by editing the `ieframe.dll.mui` file - but i'm looking for a method that can be scripted

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: should support all, or at least most recent versions

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the references in the Registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\AboutURLS`

with references like `file://c:/data/my_error.htm`

Registry entries can be modified via powershell or with cmd via the `REG` command

Comment: Thanks, but this coves anything but `dnserror.htm`